# Where can I find documentation for The Windows Phone Tool kit? Particularly for the ListPicker. (Windows Phone 8)

Tags: windows-phone-8, msdn, toolkit

Where can I find documentation for The Windows Phone Toolkit?

Particularly for the ListPicker. (Windows Phone 8)

I couldn't find it here: http://phone.codeplex.com/documentation , nor by searching with google.

Comment: What documentation are you looking for? The samples are straight forward and demonstrate how to use it, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codeplex page has sourcecode with [examples](http://phone.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest). Microsoft also has an [example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/ColorPicker-using-a2dc8041) of how to use the listpicker too.

Comment: Is there a class reference?